# jquery load function once div is shown

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to add this function when a span is shown. And also start when the div is shown. Currently it works fine but it starts as soon as the page loads. I've tried a bunch of different options with trying to do it on onclick('nextMSG();') etc and same with $(docment).onload(function){ etc

```
function nextMsg() {
if (messages.length == 0) {
  } else {
    $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(20000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    return true;
}
};

var messages = [
"Downloading Video ...",
"Converting video into a web friendly format ...",
"Combining Video and Layout ...",
"Preparing email for client ...",
"Sending email ...",
"Email sent!"
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();

});
```

Currently I have this with my onclick that doesn't work. Everything else works. It shows my images etc which is great. But I want to add in the above message so it looks like it's doing some other stuff.. more just a visual.

```
<input type="image" name="submit" src="generate-button.gif" class="submit" value="Generate Mock-up" onclick="confirm('Are you sure everything is correct?');return loadSubmit();return nextMsg();"></center>
```

I'm making it look like it's downloading a video, converting etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can't have two `return`s. Also, if you're using jQuery, why are you using the `onclick` HTML attribute?

Answer (score 1):

First ideas to clean this up a bit:

```
var messages = [
        "Downloading Video ...",
        "Converting video into a web friendly format ...",
        "Combining Video and Layout ...",
        "Preparing email for client ...",
        "Sending email ...",
        "Email sent!"
        ].reverse();
        function nextMsg(){
           if(messages.length >0){      
              $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(20000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
           }else{
             $('#message').hide();
           }
      }
$(function(){
       $(".submitimage").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         nextMsg();
       }
      }); 
 });



<input type="image" name="submitimage" src="generate-button.gif" class="submitimage" value="Generate Mock-up">
```